# Firefox won't play sounds, but works in other browsers

Tags: javascript, firefox, audio, ogg

I try to play sounds with "Howler.js", but it's not working in FF in every other browser it works. 
To test if it is a problem with the sound files I opened the directory containing the files with the browser.
I have a '.mp3' file, a '.ogg' file, a '.wav' and a '.webm' file.
In FF none of them are working, FF only gives me the message "Video could not be played, because the file is broken.".
Now I'm totally confused, because other browsers don't complain about the audio files.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you installed the latest Version of Firefox?

Comment: Yes it's the latest Version.

Comment: Try to delete und recreate the directory, where your audio files are stored. And additionally restart your PC.
I worked myself through the GitHub issues of Howler.js, but there is nothing similar to your problem...

Comment: Doesn't work.. Anyway thanks for your help

Comment: Could you add a snippet of code to show us what you're doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution myself. The problem was that I started the Code via node and gulp, which resulted in wrong mime types, which was a problem for Firefox. When the application is started via apache, the mime types are correct and everythings working fine.